# Looking for a wattpad book (Thorned Gods?) about a girl with ghostly wolf. She can change into a Wyrm

Tags: identification-request

I read this book maybe 4-5 yrs ago (no more than seven) on Wattpad. It was the first part. (that site has atrocious search & find.)

It was titled 'Thorned Gods'? It was fiction/magic set in the 21st century but hidden from humanity.

Various families and people in the know how weren't allowed to do magic or posess magical powers. These people lived lavishly. It seemed to be the only forbidden thing. Only a group of powerful beings were allowed to do magic; they punished anyone who did it. The families (people in power) had to pay tribute to these mysterious figures.

The male protagonist/love interest had purple eyes. His father and brothers too. It was a family trait or something. His mother was dead (She had some ability that she used for a good cause. She died as a punishment). And their father blamed the protag for it. The other brothers were ambivalent about the whole abuse. There was an instance, where we see the father punishing the protag with a whip and it is implied that the situation is common (the father even puts it like he is doing it for good) and even the protag finds it justifiable.

The boys' family was once reputable (sort of nobility like the girls') but something happened and their position went down quite a lot. Like really low. Part of it has to do it with the whole hunting a tribute was their job and compared to others they did some magic (I think they did.) They (the whole family) hated the girl's father and were plotting their revenge. For this, they wanted the girl. They somehow blackmailed the father (girl) to marry his daughter to the male protagonist.

The girl (female protagonist) was the daughter of someone high in position and the male protags family answered to them. Oh, the male protag had also given the girl (when she was a child) a white ghost-like (amorphous) wolf puppy that grows up to be quite large.

In one scenario, the boy ventures into the outside world for hunting (their job). Can't remember what exactly happens but the group purposely lets out a small monster (a creature) that attacks an ordinary girl on the road or something and the protag and his group save the girl (again blurry detail) and the girl is killed because she was pure/virgin? And she would make for a good tribute.

There was another scenario, at the end of the book it is confirmed that the girl has some special powers and somehow she transforms into a Wyrm. Things happened and it is revealed boy can be a Wyrm. wrangler/controller.

It's all over the place, but these are the only details I know. I just remembered it, but can't find it now (account rehaul) and this is driving me up the walls.

---

**Location:** Wattpad

**Time:** 2018-21

**Genre:** Young Adult, fiction

**Title:** Maybe 'Thorned Gods' (I think it was also used as a swear in a similar vein to 'By the thorned Gods!')

**Cover:** N/A

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like this could be ***Crows and Thorns* by Ava Larksen on Wattpad** ([book 1 here](https://www.wattpad.com/story/143367728-bound-1-of-crows-and-thorns)). It's Horned Gods, not Thorned Gods.

**(Warning: answer may contain spoilers!)**

From the intro:

> Graysen Crowther was a young lord raised in the art of violence. An iron-fisted enforcer who ruled over the crime lords and the cartels of the world for the dark sect we were born to serve - The Horned Gods.
>
> And I was a princess of the underworld, whose subjects weren't thieves and murderers, but stealers of souls, enders of lives.

> As far as I knew, there was nothing special about my family, only our placement as Great House. But me, well, I was different. No one could learn my secret, ever. If the Horned Gods discovered me, they would annihilate my entire family and every single person I loved.
>
> Especially Graysen, I could never let him learn my truth.
>
> Little did I know, while I was hiding the dark power that resided inside me, he had been hunting me all this time.  And neither of us was prepared to admit what we truly felt for the other.

- In [a later book](https://www.wattpad.com/874653405-caged-3-of-crows-and-thorns-chapter-thirty-eight), it seems that Nelle (the female protagonist) is a wyrm.
- Another [chapter](https://www.wattpad.com/amp/598966414) later in Book 1 mentions that the male protagonist's mother was killed by the Horned Gods and he has a lot of whip marks on his back.
- Near the [beginning of the first book](https://www.wattpad.com/560884469-bound-1-of-crows-and-thorns-chapter-3-five-years), the female protagonist has a "wraith-wolf [...] gifted to me by the Crowthers after signing the farce of a marriage contract [...] the nicest thing Graysen had ever done for me".
- Despite the epic fantasy feel of the setting, it does seem to be set within a 21st-century world, as the same chapter linked just above also mentions her having a contacts list in her phone and receiving messages from him.

Comment: Thank you. It's the same book. I just remembered it out of the blue and searched on wattpad but couldn't find one single helpful suggestion.